# eclipse xml error

Tags: java-me, blackberry-eclipse-plugin

i am programming in eclipse for the first time and when i create a blackberry project i am getting this error in BlackBerry_App_Descriptor.xml as

> Description Resource Path Location Type
>   InvalidRegex: Pattern value '([a-zA-Z_]{1,63}[\s-a-zA-Z_0-9.]{0,63}[;]?)*' is not a valid regular expression. The reported error was: ''-' is an invalid character range. Write '-'.' at column '19'. BlackBerry_App_Descriptor.xml /sample Unknown XML Problem

please help me out

thanks in advance.

Comment: You can watch the bug https://www.blackberry.com/jira/browse/TOOL-280

Answer (score 1):

I have had the same problem earlier with my first project on BlackBerry using the Eclipse provided on the site.

Though I took a lot of time to get a workaround for this, the solution is surprisingly simple.

Uninstall the JDK 7.x from your Windows system, adjust your path variables to point to another JDK version, preferably 6. There could be other dependencies in your Eclipse environment which need to be set independently to point to the new JDK (try Windows -> Preferences -> Java -> Installed JREs in your Eclipse and voila!)

see? let us know if you still face the problem..

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same problem as you are. There is a post regarding this issue at  http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/InvalidRegex-Pattern-value-a-zA-Z-1-63-a-zA-Z-0-9-0-63-is-not-a/td-p/944343

I haven't been able to solve the problem yet, and I am clueless as to what may be causing it. The answers at the blackberry support forums didn't work for me at all. But do try them out. Best of luck.

The deprecated version of the blackberry development IDE for eclipse (version 1.1 of the pluggin) works fine, but is not available for download anymore.

Comment: I tried deleting the contents of the file and the error remains the same. I guess this means the problem is not the file itself. The error will keep shoing up no matter what the file holds. If you delete the file it will change to somehting like "Applicatin descriptor missing".

Comment: First, uninstall JDK7. Then download and install JDK6. RIM should update system requirements for the eclipse plugin and point out that it doesn't support JDK7.

Comment: Just edit your answer to match the information in your comments.