# Error when I create a BlackBerry project

Tags: blackberry-eclipse-plugin

Description Resource Path Location Type
InvalidRegex: Pattern value '([a-zA-Z_]{1,63}[\s-a-zA-Z_0-9.]{0,63}[;]?)*' is not a valid regular expression. The reported error was: ''-' is an invalid character range. Write '-'.' at column '19'.  BlackBerry_App_Descriptor.xml   /Test   Unknown XML Problem

I'am green hand. I want to study BlackBerry. please help me! Thanks!

Comment: try this. it worked for me after i switched from JDK 7 to JDK 6 with no result. Install up-to-date black berry desktop software and connect your device.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the suggestion from this thread?
http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/problem-with-the-BlackBerry-App-Descriptor-xml-in-Eclipse-Plug/td-p/959029

It works for me, after I changed to Java 6.

Additionally you can look here:
[eclipse xml error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4224766/eclipse-xml-error)